# Is it possible to create a loop between two css classes using transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want know if its possible to make a loop purely in CSS (obviously 3) between two css classes on an element.

e.g. Imagine that I have an error box and I want its `background-color` to animation from `red` to `yellow` while its `font-size` is increasing from `18px` to `24px` then decreasing back to `18px` and do this animation continuously.

```
.state-red {
   background-color: red;
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 18px;
}


.state-yellow {
   background-color: yellow;
   color: red;
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [CSS3 animations <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) (*also see the [W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)*)

```
.state-loop{
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-name: sizeandcolor;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes sizeandcolor{    
  from{
   background-color: red;
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 18px;
  }

  to{
   background-color: yellow;
   color: red;
   font-size: 24px;
  }

}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ZtQRG/

Answer (score 0):

Gaby's answer is correct. You need and animation + keyframes because you can loop them (unlike using only a transition--you can't loop a transition).

`.state-loop`'s animation properties could be shortened to:

```
.state-loop {
    animation: sizeandcolor 2s infinite alternate;
}
```